# Using JavaScript to Open iFrame form success in parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

We are currently using JavaScript to process our forms, but the form is contained in an iFrame, which opens the success result URL in the iFrame. We would like the success result (once form is filled in) to point to the parent frame...

Script for form:

```
<script>try
{
var lastSubmission = null;
var ContactId = 0; var _wow;
var CaptureId = 12;
var PageId = 0;
var EmailId = 0;
var CampaignName = '';
var IsNewContact = false;
var IsTest = false;
var IsUserValid;
var gatorLeadsTrackingOptions = 0;
}catch(e){}
errorMessage.innerHTML ='';
successMessage.innerHTML ='';
function GatorTrim(x) { return x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');};function CaptureFormData()
{
if(lastSubmission != null){
 secondsSinceLastSubmission = (new Date().getTime() - lastSubmission) / 1000
 if(secondsSinceLastSubmission < 1) {
     return;
 }
}
var Value;
var CheckSelection = false;
var result;
var ButtonId = 6;
var submissionData = {
 captureId: CaptureId,
 buttonId: ButtonId,
 pageId: PageId,
 emailId: EmailId,
 campaignName: CampaignName,
 contactId: ContactId,
 isTest: IsTest,
 sendNotificationEmail: false,
 passGatorLeadsTrackingDataInRedirectUrl: true,
 onlyOneEntry: false,
 displayName: 'Volo Not got a code',
 emailAddress: '',
 values: [],
 gatorLeadsTrackingOptions: gatorLeadsTrackingOptions
};
document.getElementById('CaptureControlButton_6_').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('CaptureControlButton_6_').value = 'Submitting, please wait';
setTimeout(function() {try{errorMessage.innerHTML = '';
successMessage.innerHTML = '';
Value = getObject('CaptureControl_4_').value;
if(Value==''){errorMessage.innerHTML += 'The email address field is missing<br>';
document.getElementById('CaptureControlButton_6_').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('CaptureControlButton_6_').value = 'Send';
}
Value = getObject('CaptureControl_5_').value;
if(Value==''){errorMessage.innerHTML += 'Mandatory fields missing<br>';
document.getElementById('CaptureControlButton_6_').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('CaptureControlButton_6_').value = 'Send';
}
Value = getObject('CaptureControl_3_').value;
if(Value==''){errorMessage.innerHTML += 'The field name company name is missing<br>';
document.getElementById('CaptureControlButton_6_').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('CaptureControlButton_6_').value = 'Send';
}
if(errorMessage.innerHTML != ''){return;}
Value = GatorTrim(getObject('CaptureControl_4_').value);
submissionData.emailAddress = Value;


Value = GatorTrim(getObject('CaptureControl_5_').value);
if (Value != undefined) {submissionData.values.push({controlId: 5, value: Value });
}


Value = GatorTrim(getObject('CaptureControl_6_').value);
if (Value != undefined) {submissionData.values.push({controlId: 6, value: Value });
}


Value = GatorTrim(getObject('CaptureControl_3_').value);
if (Value != undefined) {submissionData.values.push({controlId: 3, value: Value });
}


var result = WebCapture.Submit(JSON.stringify(submissionData));
var response = JSON.parse(result.value);
if(response.success==false){errorMessage.innerHTML = 'You have already submitted.';
document.getElementById('CaptureControlButton_6_').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('CaptureControlButton_6_').value = 'Send';
return;}
trackingData = response.trackingData;
document.getElementById('CaptureControlButton_6_').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('CaptureControlButton_6_').value = 'Send';
successMessage.innerHTML = 'Thank you for submitting&nbsp;';
if(typeof _wow != 'undefined' && response.trackWowSubmit){
 trackUrlInWow(response.wowUrl);}
var submitRedirectUrl = 'http://takeflight.volocommerce.com/multichannel-selling/'
if(submitRedirectUrl.indexOf('?') == -1){
 submitRedirectUrl = submitRedirectUrl + '?';
}else{
 submitRedirectUrl = submitRedirectUrl + '&';
}

submitRedirectUrl += 'gator_td=' + trackingData;
window.location.href=submitRedirectUrl;
}catch(e){if(IsTest) { alert(e.message); } else { alert('An error has occurred submitting the data. Please try again.'); } 
document.getElementById('CaptureControlButton_6_').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('CaptureControlButton_6_').value = 'Send';
}
lastSubmission = new Date().getTime();
}, 100);

}</script>
```

The form (contained in an iframe on our page)

```
<style>
body {
background: #fff;
color:#000;
font-family: ‘open sans’, sans-serif;
}
input[type=text], input[type=button] {
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
height: 40px;
border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}
input[type=button] {
background-color: #F04D1D;
height: 45px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
<table style="width: 300px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><base target="_parent" />
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><font color="#f04d1d"><strong><span style="font-family: '‘open sans’', sans-serif, ';'; font-size: 24px;">GET YOUR CODE&nbsp;</span></strong></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span style="color: rgb(242, 242, 242);">&nbsp;</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name*&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Last Name*</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input name="First Name" id="CaptureControl_5_" type="text" value=""></td>
                        <td><input name="Last Name" id="CaptureControl_6_" type="text" value=""></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Company Name*</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="Company Name" id="CaptureControl_3_" type="text" value="" style="width: 300px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Your Email*</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="Email Address" id="CaptureControl_4_" type="text" value="" style="width: 300px;"><br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span style="color: rgb(242, 242, 242);">&nbsp;</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="CaptureControlButton_6_" type="button" value="Send" onclick="try{CaptureFormData(0);}catch(e){}" style="width: 300px;"><br>
            <div id="errorMessage" style="width:135;height:10;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;color:red;">Error Message Area</div>
            <div id="successMessage" style="width:135;height:10;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;">Success Message Area</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 10px;"><em>*Required field</em></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
```

**Note** The form is on a different URL/domain to our main website, where the content is held.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you'll have to use javascript (from the parent frame) to catch the submit action (in the child frame), and then somehow open the resulting page in the parent. Since your iframe comes from another domain, you will have to set up Cross-domain requests for the servers to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use window.top.location to change whole page not only iframe part.